# IPA file made by pipeline is not working in browserstack

Tags: ios, react-native, browserstack

When the pipeline finishes building react-native ios app. It creates an artifact IPA file. Usually, it works fine but for several times we get 'app_install_error: unknown ....'. Builds are fine because when we connect to testflight and download same build number all is fine and app is installed and working normally.  [image]

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Experiencing same issue, have you found out the root cause?

Comment: testers fix that but I don't know how ... sorry

Comment: Thanks, I too found a workaround but not sure what causing this yet.